# YouTube API - Public Access Key in PHP

Tags: youtube-api, google-api

how can I replace OAuth2 access to Public API Access Key in Youtube API v3? Should I use setDeveloperKey function? If I do so as showed below it returns:

> Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.

I have set my Public Access API in Google console so it should be okay.

When I try to access via OAuth it works perfectly.

```
CORRECTED CODE:
  // Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
session_start();

$API_KEY = 'AIzaSyB7HuVrtyiUV8ow1SegS6xxxxxxxxx';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setDeveloperKey($API_KEY);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
  FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
    // Call the channels.list method to retrieve information about the
    // currently authenticated user's channel.
    $channelsResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels('contentDetails', array(
      'id' => 'UUJQ2_kh7m7muj2xxxx',
    ));

    $htmlBody = '';

      $playlistItemsResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', array(
        'playlistId' => => 'UUJQ2_kh7m7muj2xxxx',
        'maxResults' => 50
      ));

      $htmlBody .= "";
      foreach ($playlistItemsResponse['items'] as $playlistItem) {
       $title =  $playlistItem['snippet']['title'];
       $video_id = $playlistItem['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];
          $htmlBody .= "<a href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$video_id."'>";
          $htmlBody .= "<img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/".$video_id."/1.jpg'>".$title."</a></br>";
      }
      $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
?>

<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Uploads</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?=$htmlBody?>
  </body>
</html>
```

ERROR ON GET:

> "domain": "usageLimits",
>       "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
>       "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."    }   ],   "code":
>   403,   "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers
>   Console to activate the API for your project."

Comment: Which request is given the error ? YouTube API version 3 is not using a developerKey. Add the api key as a parameter to your request, like: &key=AIzaSyBsRpXjl8oAymwFZ0CMxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: And how can I replace the OAuth verification by API key solution? I was trying to change the example from google developers site. Can I use this solution with API key?  I used exactly this (of course with my access key) - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#retrieve_my_uploads

Comment: OAuth 2 will also work for older api version requests as far as they are not obsolete. OAuth 2, is used to get an access_token, which is needed to access private YouTube data. Then for a GET request you can add the parameter &access_token=..... instead of &key=.....

Comment: That example "Retrieve my uploads", that you refer to: Did that example worked before you made any change in the code ?

Comment: Yes it does work fine if I use OAuth, but I want to enable my friends to see list of my uploaded videos (only public ones) and if I use OAuth they would have to log via my google account. Thats why I thought to use Public access Key but I cannot figure out how to modify the example I sent to use API key instead of OAuth.

Comment: To show public videos using api version 3 you supply only the api key. For example with the parameter &key=... (your api-key). In the channels list you change the "mine" parameter with the "id" parameter and as value "your channels-id". ( $youtube->channels->listChannels('contentDetails', array(
      'mine' => 'true',) You can't use "mine" anymore.

Comment: I corrected the code (see above) but now it alerts: Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&id=UUJQ2_kh7m7muj2-BRjYvg&key=AIzaSyB7HuVrtyiUV8ow1SegS6J6nSTcYxxxx: (403) Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project. Any help pls?

Comment: I tested your code and it has some error. I will put my changed and working code in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Changed your code. This works for me.

```
<?PHP
 // (1): Choose a valid channel_id
 $myChannelId = 'UUJQ2_kh7m7muj2xxxx';              // 'REPLACE_ME';
 // (2): api version 3
 $API_KEY = 'AIzaSyB7HuVrtyiUV8ow1SegS6xxxxxxxxx';  // 'REPLACE_ME';

 // (3): Library from: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client
 // set_include_path();  // REPLACE_ME as needed to point to your client library.
 require_once 'Google/Client.php';
 require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setDeveloperKey($API_KEY);
//$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
//$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
//  FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
//$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
    // Call the channels.list method to retrieve information about the
    // currently authenticated user's channel.
    $channelsResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels('contentDetails', array(
      'id' => $myChannelId,
    ));

    $htmlBody = '';
    foreach ($channelsResponse['items'] as $channel) {
      // Extract the unique playlist ID that identifies the list of videos
      // uploaded to the channel, and then call the playlistItems.list method
      // to retrieve that list.
      $uploadsListId = $channel['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'];
      $playlistItemsResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', array(
        'playlistId' => $uploadsListId,
        'maxResults' => 50
      ));
      $htmlBody .= " ";

      foreach ($playlistItemsResponse['items'] as $playlistItem) {
       $title =  $playlistItem['snippet']['title'];
       $video_id = $playlistItem['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];
       $htmlBody .= "<a href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$video_id."'>";
       $htmlBody .= "<img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/".$video_id."/1.jpg'>".$title."</a></br>";
      }
      $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
      }
?>

<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Uploads</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?PHP print $htmlBody?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort Als, but unfortunately it still gives me error (I also tried to generate new keys but still without success). I've put the error alert up after my initial code.

Comment: @LukášJežek I did run your code at the start: It was wrong for me too. So, I did make e few changes. Replace your code, with the updated one, so I can run ypur code again.

Comment: Thanks Als, I will try, but there might be problem somewhere else because if I use URL as follows I get errors pls see above, https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=GhMfrbbwvA0&key=AIzaSyDo5BLQ1PJ8Yi2ynSv5-uVVWZdXg2GLW8U&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status

Comment: @LukášJežek  Yes, I see it too. In my working code I only replaced my API-key with yours and then I get an error. Check the settings in the Console and generate a new API-key

Comment: Thank you Als, I tried to genereta 3 new API keys as well as create new project, but still the same. But there must be some problem in that, the code is ok. Thank you very much for your effort, if I figure it out I will give an update.

Comment: @LukášJežek I think is should be easy. Have you seen this video about api-key: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Im69kzhpR3I

Comment: So finally it started to work, I created a new project and a new API key, then I had to wait for about 8 hours (it did not work with the new api key right away too) it works :-) There must have been something stuck. THANK YOU SO MUCH Als!!!